# Error C2664 when passing an array of mutex's to a function

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I'm trying to pass an array of mutex's to a function being called by a thread. I am getting this error:

```
cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::mutex *' to 'std::mutex (&)[5]
```

Declaration

```
void Philosopher::Live(std::mutex (&fork_)[5])
```

Call

```
thread_[i] = std::thread(&Philosopher::Live, philosopher_[i], fork_);
```

Comment: Removed tag from title and turned it into a more complete sentence. Also a little reformatting

Answer (score 1):

An array of `T` used in most expressions will degrade to a pointer to `T` with value equal to the address of the first array element. The argument forwarding mechanism for templates do not know that you want to forward the argument as a reference to the array, so the array argument is passed as its degraded value.

To pass the array as a reference, you can use `std::ref`:

```
thread_[i] = std::thread(&Philosopher::Live, philosopher_[i], std::ref(fork_));
```

Alternatively, you can choose to use `std::vector` or `std::array` for `fork_`, and modify your `Live` method to take a reference to that instead.

Comment: Adding this in now gives Error C2090: function returns array, any help with this?

Comment: xrefwrap 

     typename _Callable::_MyTy(_Types...)>::type

Comment: EDIT:: I changed my declaration to use (std::mutex * fork) and it works fine now